# Is it possible to construct a field in TSQL and then reference it in the same query?

Tags: t-sql

To demonstrate what I need, this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT 
dbo.expensive_function AS test,
IIF(test=1, 3, 4) AS test2
```

But this does:

```
SELECT 
*, 
IIF(test=1, 3, 4) AS test2
FROM (
    SELECT 
    dbo.expensive_function AS test
)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this? I'm translating legacy code from Microsoft Access to SQL Server and I'm finding that I need multiple nested tables to achieve the desired results. It's also undesirable to run the expensive function twice in the query.

Comment: Yes. you can't reference the column alias on the same level. What you did is one way (derived table). Other alternative is using CTE or APPLY operator

Comment: Short answer: no. Things are not that bad, though - you are *not* running the function twice, but once.

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be any correlation between your query and the expensive function.

Execute the function before the query, store the value in a variable and use the variable in the query instead of the expensive function.